# How to count the uploaded data's through .csv in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a php code to upload a .csv file this one is working fine. But what i want is if i upload 10 records in a .csv file means it display how many records i upload and in that how many is correctly and how many's are wrong.

Here is my code :

```
if (isset($_POST["submitbutton"])) {

if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    if (pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'csv') {
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");

        //Grab the header in csv
        $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

        $not_valid = [];
        $i = 1;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $aValid = false;
            $field1 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);
            $field2 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);
            $field3 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);
            $field4 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);
            $field5 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);
            $field6 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]);
            $field7 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]);
            $field8 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]);
            $field9 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]);



            $sql2 = "select * from m_tl_mastercourse where LMS_Course_ID='$field9'";
            $check1 = mysql_query($sql2);


            $sql = "select * from mdl_course where id='".$field9."'";
            $check = mysql_query($sql);

            $row=mysql_fetch_array($check);



            if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0 && mysql_num_rows($check1) < 1) {
                $aValid = true;
            } else {
                $not_valid[] = $i;

            }




            if ($aValid) {
                echo count($i);
                $import = "INSERT into m_tl_mastercourse values('','$field1','$field2','$field3','$field4','$field5','$field6','$field7','$field8','$field9')";
                mysql_query($import);
                $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
                    if($last_id){
                         $sql = "select m_tl_mastercourse.Id, Course_Type from m_tl_mastercourse inner join  mdl_course where m_tl_mastercourse.LMS_Course_ID = mdl_course.id ";
                $ret = get_records_sql($sql);
                foreach ($ret as $index => $obj) {
                    $master_id = $obj->Id;
                    $course_type = $obj->Course_Type;
                }
                echo $master_id;
                echo $course_type;

                $query = mysql_query("update m_tl_course INNER JOIN m_tl_mastercourse ON m_tl_course.course_id = m_tl_mastercourse.LMS_Course_ID SET m_tl_course.course_type='$course_type',m_tl_course.master_id='$master_id' WHERE m_tl_course.master_id='' ");

                    }

            }

            $i++;
        }
        fclose($handle);


        if (!empty($not_valid)) {

            $v_ids = implode(', ', $not_valid);

            echo count($v_ids);
            echo "Please check the following csv Row Number's - " . $v_ids;
        } else {
            echo "Master Courses Uploaded Successfully";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('csv files only allowed to upload')</script>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Please select a file')</script>";
  }
 }

   ?>
```

How to get like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are already in your code: `$i` is incremented on each loop, and `$not_valid` is an array containing the row numbers for any rows that are evaluated as not valid.

You can use `count($not_valid)` to get the number.

```
// $i starts at 1 and is incremented on the completion of each loop so will end 1 more than the total rows
$total_rows = $i - 1;
$valid_rows = $i - 1 - count($not_valid);
$invalid_rows = count($not_valid);
```